# Webkit rendering box-shadows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, webkit

I can't figure out how these are happening:

http://d.pr/i/PHJF

Has anyone experienced these types of box shadows being rendered? It appears to happen when I use JavaScript/jQuery to append some elements to the DOM.

Any insight would be great!

Comment: Please provide some code or something that would make it possible to answer without guessing. That would be great if you wanted a *paper effect*. it looks pretty nice :)

Comment: @Pinocchio If you look here: http://www.tushiesandtantrums.com/products/practical-cotton-car - click 'Buy Now,' change the State to Tennesee, and you see it happen on the ticket on the right side. The image that is showing through has a blur filter on it with css. It's like it's not acknowledging the z-index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! For anyone that runs into issues like this:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css

Specifically used the backface-visibility and perspective to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="box effect2">
box
</div>
```

css

```
.box {
    width:70%;
    height:200px;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:40px auto;
}

/*==================================================
 * Effect 2
 * ===============================================*/
.effect2
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect2:before, .effect2:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.effect2:after
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```